# Simplification of Power Function with Rational Exponent

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function, rational-functions

I'm stumped by an example in my precalculus book.

They show the simplification of a rational power function as

$x^{\alpha - \beta} > \frac{b}{a}$, so $x > (\frac{b}{a})^\frac{1}{\alpha - \beta} = (\frac{b}{a})^{\beta - \alpha}$

My question is about the simplification of that last part.  How do they clear the denominator in the exponent from $x > (\frac{b}{a})^\frac{1}{\alpha - \beta} = (\frac{b}{a})^{\beta - \alpha}$?